# Print from a specific element in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of strings on lenght n.

I would like to only print out the values after a certain element, regardless of the amount of elements before or after.

Is there anyway to do this?

**EDIT CODE**

```
string separator = "\\";
string[] splitPath = path.Split('\\');
string joinedPath = String.Join(separator, splitPath[3], splitPath[4], splitPath[5]);
Console.WriteLine("Extracted: " + path);
```

I have it being rejoined at 3 because I know the array, but I want it so that it willdo it no matter the location

And nope its not homework ;) I've a console app thats printing out a big long path, i only want it to show part of that path, not just the file. I was thinking of deleting/removing the elements up to x and then joining them back up.

Comment: Yeah, loop over the array starting at the index of your "certain element". Seems like homework?

Comment: @Morawski Have put in the code

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it right...you can use LINQ:

```
var result = yourArray.Skip(x);
```

or if you want to take only some strings:

```
var result = yourArray.Skip(x).Take(y);
```

don't forget:

```
using Sytem.Linq;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var element in myStringList.Skip(myStringList.IndexOf("certainElement"))
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public void PrintArray(int fromIndex, string[] strings)
{
     if(strings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("strings");
     if(fromIndex > strings.Length) throw new ArgumentException("Bad fromIndex", "fromIndex");

     for(int i = fromIndex; i < strings.Length; i++)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(strings[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// 'array' is the string array and 'startFrom' is where in the array you want to start from
string[] array = ...;
int startFrom = 5;
for(int count = startFrom; count < array.Length; count ++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[count]);
    // Or use array[count] for something else.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple little example:

```
int myIndex = 5;
string[] test = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" };
for (int i = myIndex; i < test.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Element: " + i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Well it's F, incorrect. For printing out `i.ToString()` (just consecutive numbers), why would you need any `string[] test` at all? ;)

Comment: Force of habit, typed it out real quick. Bit confused by this line `Well it's F, incorrect.`? The string array may be consecutive numbers but that's irrelevant, it still demonstrates a possible solution to this question.

Comment: Just a joke referring to the fact that the question is probably OP's homework ;) He needs to print values from the array anyhow - not indexes - so what he actually needs is rather `Console.WriteLine(test[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myArr.Skip(someAmount)));
```